# Working on a Word Macro in a different IDE

Tags: vba, visual-studio, ms-word

I've been working on an extensive macro in word that takes a large document and deletes sections based on data from an excel spreadsheet.  There is a vbs script that acts as the "head" of the program, which opens both excel and word as objects and runs a macro (with a few args) in the document in order to delete the sections.

I've been editing and debugging the macro in the default macro editor within word and it leaves a lot to be desired.  Is there any way to import this project into visual studio in order to edit it in a better enviorment?

Example head code

```
'Appendix Start Gen
 If AppC <> "000" Then
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(curDir & "\xxxxx.docm",,True)
    objDoc.SaveAs(curDir & "\Results\" & outputfile & " - xxxxx.docm")
    objDoc.Close
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(curDir & "\Results\" & outputfile & " - xxxxx.docm")
    objWord.Run "Macro", Filename, SectionNumber, DocumentType
    objDoc.Save
    objDoc.Close
    SectionNumber = SectionNumber +1

End If
```

Comment: If you want to spice up the VBEditor, you might consider [rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/).

Comment: "Unrealistic": the sheer amount of work and reverse-engineering should be enough, but to top it off, VBA SDK are not distributed anymore, the existing licensees are grandfathered, but there can't be any new VBA host. No new legal ones anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Rubberduck now and it's been a great help.  Seeing as its your project Mathieu, I appreciate all the effort you've put into it!